# How to make the popup div draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

i'm trying to make a popup to draggable. does anyone help me  how to do that, here is my code

http://jsfiddle.net/Ur5Xn/38/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function showAlertBox(){
     $("#alert").css("display","inherit");
     $("#content").addClass("back");
    }
    function removeAlertBox(){
        $("#alert").css("display","none");
         $("#content").removeClass("back");        
    }



    $("#alertClose").click(function(){
       removeAlertBox(); 
    });
    $("#alertShow").click(function(){
       showAlertBox(); 
    });

    $( "#alert" ).draggable();

});
```

Comment: Your code works fine, you just forgot to include jquery-ui, which is where `draggable` comes from.

Comment: Izzey is onto it, just include `jquery-ui` plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not load Jquery UI in your fiddle. It works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Just turn on JQuery Ui. You can try enabling it in JSfiddle, on the right top corner and see that your code works.

Answer (score 1):

your code is working good kindly include plugin script after the jquery plugin..
it will sureky work..

Answer (score 1):

Just try to check "jQuery UI 1.10.3" (top left of the page) in your JSfiddle, it works with me.